# mysql select record that matches 1 condition or another

Tags: mysql

I have this sample data:

```
id vendor   date   status
4   2   2020-04-15  2
266 2   2020-04-20  2
886 2   2020-05-07  2
5   3   2020-04-15  1
6   3   2020-04-15  0
8   3   2020-04-15  2
```

I am trying to select the record for each vendor where the either the status is 0 (taking priority over the next condition) or if that condition is not met, the latest record by date for each vendor.

Sample SQL:

```
select id, case
when status != 0 then id
else id
end
from
(select id, vendor, date, status
from sent
where vendor in (2,3)
group by id, vendor,  date, status
order by vendor) as inner_table
group by vendor, id;
```

Comment: your column names in query does not match to data sample

Comment: @Alex fixed, sorry about that

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: version 5.7 of MySQL @Nick

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to `UNION` all records that have `status = 0` with all records that have `MAX(date)` for a given `vendor`, but excluding max date records for those vendors that have a record with a status of 0:

```
SELECT *
FROM sent
WHERE status = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT sent.*
FROM sent
JOIN (
  SELECT vendor, MAX(date) AS max_date
  FROM sent
  GROUP BY vendor
) d ON d.vendor = sent.vendor 
   AND d.max_date = sent.date
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM sent s2
  WHERE s2.vendor = d.vendor
    AND s2.status = 0
)
ORDER BY vendor
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
id      vendor  date        status
886     2       2020-05-07  2
6       3       2020-04-15  0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2MvhDent7Z8LLuTR9fLJgQ/0)